# Face Detection in Vuforia Unity Android

Tags: unity, c#, vuforia

I am working on face detection in unity.I have tried out a face tracking sample from the below link.It worked fine

https://github.com/marcteys/unityFaceTracking

The problem is that,when I runned the above project,Am show with a separate camera view window for detection. But when we consider unity android,the tracking should be done through phone camera.

Is there any option other than OpenCV.

Please help me out